# Css Hacks a right way?

Tags: html, css

Is there is any way to write html and css without using css hacks which will work in all the browsers including ie6 -- Only using divs and not tables? I want the page to work right with both html and css, and also be w3c compliant.

Comment: You have to be more specific. What design are you trying to implement? The wholy grail?

Comment: @David Archer: I think he means some CSS quirks like the `* html` selector for IEs of version ≤ 6.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

Here's an example:

```
/* Start CSS */

/* End CSS */
```

As to if it possible to achieve the specific result you want, then … *maybe* — but you have to tell us what that is first!

Comment: Using conditional comments to add classes then in your CSS target those classes. I don't think a blank CSS file is very helpful :)

Comment: @wilmoore — please note that the important part of the answer is held in the paragraph at the end of the question, and not in the humorous code example at the top. There are lots of ways to write CSS that works the same on every browser (including a stylesheet consisting of only comments), but there isn't a general solution that will achieve any effect everywhere, and coverage of workarounds to every possible inconsistency is too broad a topic for a SO question.

Comment: Actually, it is a pretty accepted practice these days that conditional comments + a single stylesheet + browser specific classes are the way to go. I think the poster's question was fine and I'm not sure why your answer (which isn't really an answer) got up-voted. I hope it doesn't sound rude, but I just don't think it helps anyone when non-answers get up-voted.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) and have an additional stylesheet specifically for problem versions of IE6.  It does mean you have special cases, but not really hacks.

Comment: Problem with this is that there is now an additional HTTP request and adds additional rendering time. It also moves styles to another file which can be hard to debug. It is better to use conditional comments to add classes then in your CSS target those classes.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases yes, but often not. The one thing that seems to always end up as a problem is the lack of min-height in ie6.

Answer (score 0):

It has come to the point in time where one must simply resolve to no longer support IE6. It's tough, but there you have it.

There's no "right way" to do hacks. That's what "hack" means.

Comment: I don't think so. I just looked at the wiki for browser share, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers.  I get ie6 still having about 6% share, almost as much as safari

Comment: But while Safari's share is increasing, IE6's share is decreasing. And stopping support for it, will only make it decrease faster. (hopefully)

Comment: +1 - Not always appropriate for all clients, but for 95% of websites, yes.

Comment: There are good ways to target specific browsers without the hacks so just blindly telling all developers to not support IE6 isn't practical. Unfortunately, not all developers have say-so over what browser their audience uses.

Comment: The op asked how to post without using hacks to get proper results.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the design.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Keep IE6 from going into Quirks mode and you won't encounter too many problems. You may also want to consider using a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/), although sometimes you just can't avoid having to write some IE specific hack to have it look good... What exactly is your problem with using them?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in general, yes, this is absolute possible to achieve. But you will probably have to make som comprimises on how advanced your layout is going to be, or on how well you will support older browsers like IE 6.

If you are new to this field I would install the [Html Validator add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249) and surf around the web, to get an idear of what pages validate 100 % and the see what layouts they have used.